# How to check "simplification sensibility" of a geometry?

Tags: postgis, simplify

It is expected that a "geometry simplification" is a good practice to preserve stable versions of a geometry, avoiding  minor and non-relevant changes (side effect of geometry-editors and other "false updates").

The functions [ST_Simplify](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html), ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology or [ST_SimplifyVW](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SimplifyVW.html) seems good candidates. It is important

- to **preserve  original geometry** when it not needs simplification;
- to **control the "need less simplification"** by a parameter, like *tolerance*.

So, the hypothesis is that we can **check sensibility** by changing a tolerance parameter.

... But it is not working, so the question is **"How to check sensibility?"** in that context.

I am testing `ST_Simplify(geom,0.00001)=geom` and is false.. But even `ST_AsGeoJSON(geom,3)=ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Simplify(geom,0.00000001),3)`  is false!!

EXAMPLE:

```
 origianal  = ... [-60.931,2.64],[-60.929,2.638],[-60.925,2.635],[-60.919,2.63],[-60.917,2.628],...

 simplified = ... [-60.931,2.64],[-60.925,2.635],[-60.919,2.63],[-60.917,2.628],...
```

---

### Usage context

I need to preserve stable versions into a *git* repository of GeoJSON files.

PS: if a "non-invasive simplification algorithm" not exists (**?**), them, a workaround,  a simple way to normalize geometry for *git* stable versions is to apply something as `ST_buffer(ST_buffer(geom,0.000001),-0.000001)`.

Comment: Using the original sample you give, the simplified output contains all source points. Also don't forget that if 1 point was removed, the equality between the source and the simplified geometry will be false.

Comment: Thanks @JGH, you show the correct direction for a good answer... I need to test other operators tham  `=`, maybe  [ST_Contains](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) or even [ST_Equals](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html) (as guide say *" a 'better' answer than `=`"*)... If all the removed points lie on the same original geometry, the st_simplify() is preserving geometry (!).

Answer (score 1):

The @JGH comment showed the way to solve the problem. It is possible to compare original geometry *g* with the simplified one by ST_Equals:

```sql
SELECT ST_equals(g, ST_SimplifyVW(g,0.000000000001) ) eq  FROM t; -- false...
SELECT ST_equals(g, ST_SimplifyVW(g,0.0000000000001) ) eq FROM t; -- true!
```

Checking all possibilities:

```sql
WITH calc AS (
  SELECT tol, g, 
         ST_Simplify(g,tol) s, ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(g,tol) stp,
         ST_SimplifyVW(g,tol) svw  
  FROM t, (VALUES (0.01),(0.0000000000051),(0.000000000001),(0.0000000000001)) v(tol)
) SELECT tol tolerance, (g=s) eqq_s, 
         ST_equals(g,s) eq_s, ST_equals(g,stp) eq_stp, ST_equals(g,svw) eq_svw,
         ST_contains(g,s) ct_s, ST_contains(g,stp) ct_stp, ST_contains(g,svw) ct_svw
  FROM calc;
```

Result:

```
    tolerance    | eqq_s | eq_s | eq_stp | eq_svw | ct_s | ct_stp | ct_svw
-----------------+-------+------+--------+--------+------+--------+--------
            0.01 | f     | f    | f      | f      | f    | f      | f
 0.0000000000051 | f     | t    | t      | f      | t    | t      | f
  0.000000000001 | f     | t    | t      | f      | t    | t      | f
 0.0000000000001 | f     | t    | t      | t      | t    | t      | t
```

Conclusion:

- The best seems to use *st_equals()* and *ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(g,t)*, for near-zero tolerance.
- The `=` is not valid for simplification, use *st_equals* or *st_contains* to compare original and simplified geometries.
- Simplification algorithm *ST_SimplifyVW* is the worst. The *ST_Simplify* is good and good tham *ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology*, but to preserve topology is a goood practice in this context.

Comment: interesting comparison, thanks! The conclusion for `st_contains` should be reconsidered because is relies on the location of the removed vertices (result will be true if removed vertex is inside the source polygon, but will be false if it was outside of the polygon)

Comment: Hi @JGH, your comment makes sense, maybe we should to test the sensitivity against some kind of `st_buffer` operation to extract a "polygon-border of width *w*", where *w* is the tolerance. By other hand, comparison of "similar things" relies on a specific concept of similarity... It is not absolute, it is relative to the user's view, a user concept of similarity.  When a user is looking for preserving-area operations, the `st_contains` make sense. PS: in the perspective of my answer, where my choice was `st_equals`, the *contains* discussion is about a secondary use case.